# Mysql Error in Installation of Pimcore Xampp Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, pimcore

I have try to install Pimcore "Advanced Demo Package (E-Commerce, PIM, MDM, DAM, ...)" package and it'll return me following error,

```
9/10 [=========================>--]  90%
 Trying to install assets as relative symbolic links.

 --- ------------------------------------------ ------------------ 
      Bundle                                     Method / Error    
 --- ------------------------------------------ ------------------ 
  ✔   PimcoreAdminBundle                         relative symlink  
  ✔   PimcoreCoreBundle                          relative symlink  
  ✔   PimcoreEcommerceFrameworkBundle            relative symlink  
  ✔   OutputDataConfigToolkitBundle              relative symlink  
  ✔   Web2PrintToolsBundle                       relative symlink  
  ✔   PimcoreCustomerManagementFrameworkBundle   relative symlink  
  ✔   ObjectMergerBundle                         relative symlink  
 --- ------------------------------------------ ------------------ 

 [OK] All assets were successfully installed.                                   

 [ERROR] The following errors were encountered during installation                                      

 * **An exception occurred while executing 'SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE Table_type = 'BASE TABLE'':**

Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=11521
```

---

I can see this issue happen because it'll not select database first, without selecting database it'll try to run SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE Table_type = 'BASE TABLE' command.

After installation i can see it not create system admin account as well.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution to this, I hope my experience is helpful to others.

I have remove xampp installation and manually install apache,mariadb 10.01, mysql 5.7, php 7.1.

Now I can install without any issue. I hope this'll helpful to others as well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Another nice way of getting pimcore installed locally is to use docker ;)
https://github.com/dpfaffenbauer/pimcore-docker-compose

At the time of writing there is some issue with permissions, so it would require a

`chown -R www-data: .`

after all steps have been followed. But should be pretty simple to install on ubuntu. I recommend docker if you work on multiple projects, it keeps dependencies/services separated, so no need to worry about php/mysql versions and etc.